# Unit Testing throwing exception in async method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to assert an exception which happens in an async method.
Unfortunately, the assertion doesn't work.

I've made sure via debugging, that the `throw new Exception(...)` is called in the `SaveCategoriesAsync(...)` method.

The method with the `Action` normally works for unit tests... but it seems that it doesn't work with async.

I'm using **FakeItEasy** as mocking framework and **FluentAssertions** as assertion framework.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveCategoriesAsync_When_Then()
{
    A.CallTo(() => this.articleRepository.GetArticles(A<IList<long>>._)).Returns(new List<ArticleModel>());

    Action action = async () => await this.testee.SaveCategoriesAsync(new List<int>());

    action.ShouldThrow<Exception>();
}
```

What do I have to change to be able to assert the exception?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot catch exceptions in different threads. If the ShouldThrow() method doesn't do something special, it wont work. Check if your assertion framework provides a way for async actions to detect exception or write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually quite similar to what I tried. But with async, you have to use a `Func<Task>` instead of an action:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveCategoriesAsync_When_Then()
{
    A.CallTo(() => this.articleRepository.GetArticles(A<IList<long>>._)).Returns(new List<ArticleModel>());

    Func<Task> func = async () => await this.testee.SaveCategoriesAsync(new List<int>());

    func.ShouldThrow<Exception>();
}
```

Comment: What namespace is the ShouldThrow method in?

Comment: @ChrisO the ShouldThrow is in the FluentAssertions nuget package

Answer (score 2):

If it is easy to change the test runner, consider [NUnit](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnit-Documentation). Then your code would look:

```
...
Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await this.testee.SaveCategoriesAsync(new List<int>());
...
```